# Install BLAS DLLs separately or there is a full package or another soloution

Tags: c++, dll, blas, cmake-gui

I am configuring a project via `CMAKE 3.10.1` with `MinGW`.also I installed `BLAS` from sources(compiled with CMAKE) .I got Two `DLL` files. `libblas.dll` and `liblapack.dll`.I see only `BLAS_blas_LIBRARY` is pointed to `C:/Windows/System32/libblas.dll`. others not.such as :

```
BLAS_Accelerate_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_acml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_acml_mp_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_complib.sgimath_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_cxml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_dxml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_essl_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_f77blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_goto2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_mkl_intel_c_dll_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_mkl_intel_lp64_dll_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_openblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_scsl_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_sgemm_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_sunperf_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_vecLib_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

only

```
BLAS_blas_LIBRARY       C:/Windows/System32/libblas.dll
```

The CMake stop at this error :

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:699 (message):
  A required library with BLAS API not found.  Please specify library
  location.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:155 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

so I should install all of those `DLL`s separately(I searched and googled a lot,there are not integrated)  or there is a full `BLAS` package?or problem is with something else.

here is :
[my Cmake snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f5mP.jpg)

here is :
[all my instruction](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries_mingw)

Comment: I believe the `LIBRARY-NOTFOUND` part is correct. The other variables are for different vendors of blas.

Comment: So what should I do as a brief?

Comment: I actually use blas with CMake on windows in one of my projects at work and don't have the problem you are having. Although I have not looked at the CMake part for 5 years or so. It still builds for me. I will try to take a look at it tomorrow if I can. With that said I am using Visual Studio and not mingw. Also I have not installed the dlls to my windows system folder.

Comment: For your project,does it have many blas libraries in cmake-GUI ?I know you configured successfully.OK.thanks

Comment: I think it is only what you observe here.

Comment: Which version for visual studio,intell parallel studio and cmake do you use?

Comment: If you want a simple solution, there are precompiled libraries at http://OpenBLAS.net

Comment: Windows should find DLLs that you put in the same directory as the executable (which is arguably a security hole).  And make sure you’re linking them in with the executable, if the problem shows up then?

Comment: What is the complicated solution?this may cover openblas what about the other libraries?

Comment: I saw openblas zip file.the above libraries don't in it as filename except some of them.so do you mean if i compile that as dll would cover all desired libraries?for example about f77blas and so far